# Why does this distribution look completely different after splitting into groups?

Tags: r, distributions

I've got some data that represents two groups, with a before and after result for both groups. When I plot the data together, it looks as though the after is much tighter around the mean. However, when I plot the groups individually, that picture changes drastically. If anyone could help me understand why this is so, I would greatly appreciate it. I've pasted the R code below.

[image: together]

[image: group 1]

[image: group 2]

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

my_df <- structure(list(Group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1), Status = c("Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", 
"Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", 
"Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", 
"Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", 
"Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", 
"Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", 
"Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", 
"Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "Before", "After", "After", 
"After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "Before", "After", 
"Before", "Before", "Before", "After", "After", "After", "After", 
"After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", 
"After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", 
"After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", 
"After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", 
"After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", 
"After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", 
"After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", "After", 
"After", "After", "After", "After"), Result = c(2.39000010490417, 
2.00999999046326, 2.26999998092651, 2.4300000667572, 4.19999980926514, 
4.01999998092651, 4.26999998092651, 4.01999998092651, 4.1399998664856, 
4.05000019073486, 4.30999994277954, 4.01999998092651, 4.01999998092651, 
2.47000002861023, 2.25, 2.39000010490417, 4.28999996185303, 4.09000015258789, 
4.1399998664856, 4, 4.23999977111816, 4.17000007629395, 4.21000003814697, 
4.1399998664856, 4.57999992370605, 2.24000000953674, 2.44000005722046, 
2.42000007629395, 3.83999991416931, 4.01000022888184, 3.75, 4.01000022888184, 
3.78999996185303, 3.85999989509583, 3.94000005722046, 3.96000003814697, 
4.17000007629395, 4, 4.32000017166138, 4.07999992370605, 2.46000003814697, 
2.60999989509583, 2.23000001907349, 2.13000011444092, 4.46999979019165, 
4.09000015258789, 4.1100001335144, 4.17000007629395, 3.86999988555908, 
4.5, 3.9300000667572, 2.15000009536743, 2.35999989509583, 4.46999979019165, 
4.48000001907349, 4.3600001335144, 4.19000005722046, 4.28000020980835, 
4.82999992370605, 4.15000009536743, 4.42000007629395, 4.15000009536743, 
4.19999980926514, 4.44000005722046, 4.21999979019165, 4.38000011444092, 
3.94000005722046, 4.57000017166138, 2.32999992370605, 2.44000005722046, 
2.09999990463257, 2.17000007629395, 2.17000007629395, 2.61999988555908, 
4.09999990463257, 3.85999989509583, 4.15999984741211, 4.19000005722046, 
4.09999990463257, 3.97000002861023, 4.19999980926514, 4.32999992370605, 
4.07999992370605, 3.8199999332428, 4.01999998092651, 4.15999984741211, 
3.9300000667572, 4.1399998664856, 3.77999997138977, 4.11999988555908, 
4.53999996185303, 4.07000017166138, 2.54999995231628, 2.50999999046326, 
2.4300000667572, 2.32999992370605, 3.85999989509583, 3.92000007629395, 
4.3600001335144, 4.30000019073486, 4.34000015258789, 4.1399998664856, 
4.25, 4.13000011444092, 4.03999996185303, 4.26999998092651, 4.32000017166138, 
4.11999988555908, 4.05000019073486, 4.44000005722046, 4.1100001335144, 
4.19000005722046, 4.28000020980835, 4.51999998092651, 4.07999992370605, 
4.07000017166138, 4.05000019073486, 4.46000003814697, 4.05000019073486, 
2.52999997138977)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -120L
), .Names = c("Group", "Status", "Result"))

my_df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(Result, fill=Status), alpha=.3) 

my_df %>% 
  filter(Group == 1) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(Result, fill=Status), alpha=.3) 

my_df %>% 
  filter(Group == 2) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(Result, fill=Status), alpha=.3)
```

Comment: You're using a library here that you don't import.  Where do `filter` and `%>%` (and, for completeness, `ggplot`) come from?

Comment: You might just be seeing the effects of different bandwidths being chosen for each density estimate.

Comment: @MatthewDrury - Fixed

Comment: @eipi10 - Not sure I understand. I'd have expected the distribution to possibly distort, but that the relationship would remain the same. The relationships appear very different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're seeing the effect of R choosing different bandwidths for the grouped and ungrouped plots. A smaller bandwidth will result in greater resolution (along the horizontal axis) of peaks and valleys in the data, while a larger bandwidth will smear them out. You can see this if you set the bandwidths yourself:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(ggplot(my_df) +
                           geom_density(aes(Result, fill=Status), alpha=.3, bw=0.2)  +
                           facet_grid(Group ~ .) + ggtitle("bw=0.2"),
                         ggplot(my_df) + geom_density(aes(Result, fill=Status), alpha=.3, bw=0.05)  +
                           facet_grid(Group ~ .) + ggtitle("bw=0.05"), ncol=2),
             arrangeGrob(ggplot(my_df) +
                           geom_density(aes(Result, fill=Status), alpha=.3, bw=0.2) +
                           ggtitle("bw=0.2"),
                         ggplot(my_df) +
                           geom_density(aes(Result, fill=Status), alpha=.3, bw=0.05) +
                           ggtitle("bw=0.05"), ncol=2),
             ncol=1, heights=c(3,2))
```

Notice that the grouped and ungrouped plots are the same (save for scaling) when the bandwidths (`bw`) are the same.

[image]

I'm not sure if there's a way to extract the chosen bandwidth from within ggplot. However, ggplot is using the `density` function to generate the density plot, and `density` uses `bw.nrd0` to choose the bandwidth. So let's use `bw.nrd0` to see what bandwidths are being chosen. In the output below, notice how R chooses narrower bandwidths when considering each group separately, as compared with the case where both groups are combined.

Each `Status` separately:

```
sapply(split(my_df, my_df$Status), function(d) {bw.nrd0(d$Result)})
```

> ```
> After    Before 
> 0.1224065 0.2983324
> ```

Each `Group` and `Status` separately:

```
sapply(split(my_df, interaction(my_df$Status, my_df$Group)), function(d) {bw.nrd0(d$Result)})
```

> ```
> After.1   Before.1    After.2   Before.2 
> 0.09229781 0.07725860 0.07847190 0.06391614
> ```

**UPDATE:** Regarding your comment, do you mean the "spike" in the uppermost plot in your question? I think this is a scaling effect due to the relative number of points in each group.

```
my_df %>% group_by(Group, Status) %>% tally %>% ungroup %>% 
    mutate(Percent=round(n/sum(n)*100,1))
```

> ```
>   Group Status     n Percent
>   <dbl>  <chr> <int>   <dbl>
> 1     1  After    13    10.8
> 2     1 Before    14    11.7
> 3     2  After    52    43.3
> 4     2 Before    41    34.2
> ```

Note that `Group==2` has many more observations than `Group==1`. If we equalize the number of observations in each group, then this scaling effect goes away:

```
grid.arrange(my_df %>% 
               ggplot() +
               geom_density(aes(Result, fill=Status), alpha=.3) +
               ggtitle("Original Data"),
             my_df %>% 
               group_by(Status, Group) %>%
               sample_n(100, replace=TRUE) %>%
               ggplot() + 
               geom_density(aes(Result, fill=Status), alpha=.3) +
               ggtitle("Resampled so each group has equal number of data points"), ncol=1)
```

[image]

You might find it easier to compare groups using another type of plot. Below are box and violin plots. The latter is a density plot, but each group's "violin" is scaled so that they all have the same area, which might make it easier to compare the shapes and locations of each distribution.

```
grid.arrange(ggplot(my_df, aes(x=factor(Group), y=Result, colour=Status)) +
               geom_boxplot(width=0.4, position=position_dodge(0.5))  + theme_bw(),
             ggplot(my_df, aes(x=factor(Group), y=Result, colour=Status)) +
               geom_violin(bw=0.07)  + theme_bw(), ncol=2)
```

[image]

Or a histogram, which will show you where the data points are, without the model-based smoothing of the density estimate (though of course the binwidth will affect the shape of the plot):

```
grid.arrange(ggplot(my_df) +
               geom_histogram(aes(Result, fill=Status), alpha=.4, binwidth=0.1)  +
               facet_grid(Group ~ .) + theme_bw(),
             ggplot(my_df) +
               geom_histogram(aes(Result, fill=Status), alpha=.4, , binwidth=0.1) + theme_bw(), 
             ncol=1, heights=c(3,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to tell which bandwidth ggplot is picking? I feel like you're right, but the plot I get when I run this looks different and I want to test this with the bandwidth ggplot is picking.

Comment: Added images in my question so you could see what I'm seeing. My "together" plot looks nothing like your bw=0.2 plots. I'm pretty sure you're correct, but if there is a way to tell which bw ggplot is picking, I could prove that to myself. Thanks for all the explanation so far.

Comment: I really appreciate the answers, but I've tried a bunch of different binwidths, spanning from .03 to .3 on group 2, and none of them produce that spike in After that you see on the right hand side of my first chart. Are you able to re-produce that? Sorry for all the follow up questions, but I'm curious, and I know I will be asked to explain the difference.

Comment: Thank you again. I really appreciate all the time you spent on this, and I learned about violin plots, which I will look into further.